# Bind a jquery event to an array of jquery objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have an array containing jquery objects which are later referenced in various parts of the code. I put them into an array so that they are only selected once, rather than doing a jquery select every time I need to access them.

My question is, how can I bind a jquery event to an array of these jquery objects?

I used to do a jquery select on the IDs of the elements and then bind the event:

```
$('#name, #domain, #description').bind("blur change", 
function () { 
    callEventHandler(this); 
});
```

Now I have this array of jQuery objects. How can I bind these to a jquery event?

```
var jqObjs = [$('#name'), $('#domain'), $('#description')];
```

I tried doing this, but it didn't work:

```
$(jqObjs).bind("blur change", 
function () { 
    callEventHandler(this); 
});
```

Comment: I'd of course question why these are stored as jQuery objects in the array rather than just dom elements. Or why the array isn't itself a jQuery object containing just the dom elements.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to keep doing a jQuery select on these elements over and over again and opted for doing the select once, and storing the jQuery objects in an array. They are jQuery objects because jQuery commands are performed on them throughout the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can loop over them:

```
$(jqObjs).each(function(_, jQobj){
    jQobj.on("blur change",function () { 
       callEventHandler(this); 
    });
});
```

Since `bind()` uses `on()` internally I switched to use `on()` instead.

An alternative would just store selectors

```
var jqSelectors = ['#name', '#domain', '#description'];
$(jqObjs.join()).on('...
```

I think it would help to understand how you even arrived at getting this array created. There are likely other approaches depending on use and what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Thanks. I had considered looping through them as well, but I just wasn't sure if there was a better way to do it, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: I prefer not to store just the selectors (per your 2nd suggestion) because I am using these jquery objects in other parts of the code as well. So in order to avoid having to keep doing a jquery select on these elements every time I want to access them, I'm storing the jquery objs in an array once, and then accessing those objects throughout the code.

Comment: but how is array created? Might be simpler leaving it in jQuery object stored as variable

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by leaving it in a jQuery object stored as a variable?

Comment: if you use `$('#id1,#id2').doSomething()` and want to use those again you can store that in a variable ... `var $items = $('#id1,#id2').doSomething();` then later on you can do `$items.anotherThing()`

Comment: It's known as caching a collection to save searching for the same thing again...BUT... need to make sure that if it's a class of elements that might get added/removed in between that the cached version will include any and all that existed at the time code was run...not future ones

Comment: Gotcha. So you're saying to group all of the elements into one jQuery select statement and store that into a variable. Then I would use that variable throughout the code. This would work perfectly. However, this particular case is the only time when I need to bind an event to all four of those elements. The rest of the code applies different things to each of these elements separately, thus I cannot continue using them all together in one variable. So I need them to be separated into their own jQuery objects.

Comment: Thanks for the "loop" suggestion. I will mark that as the correct answer since that works.

Comment: Can also filter a collection ... `$items.filter('.SomeSpecificClass').doSomething()` ..or ... `$items.filter(':has(img)').doSomething()` as examples

Answer (score 4):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031991/430742 you can use jQuery's `map()` to create a jQuery list object from your array. This object can then be used with `.on()` to bind events to its elements.

```js
var jqObjs = [$('#name'), $('#domain'), $('#description')];

var listObj = $.map(jqObjs, function(el){return el.get()});
$(listObj).on('click', function(ev){
 console.log('EVENT TRIGGERED');
});
```

```css
button{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="name">Button 'name'</button>
<button id="domain">Button 'domain'</button>
<button id="description">Button 'description'</button>
```