# Group similar jquery click events together

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to group together jQuery click events for similar elements. Basically, I have the main div I want to add new classes to when a particular button is clicked. So I have

```
    <div class="main"></div>
```

and I want to add new classes to that div depending on a few buttons I have

```
    <div class="triggers">
      <div class="changer" id="blue">Blue</div>
      <div class="changer" id="red">Red</div>
      <div class="changer" id="green">Green</div>
    </div>
```

So I have the classes made up in CSS and then of course add them to the main div based on each of those buttons ID's being clicked

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#blue').click(function() {
      $(".main").addClass("blue").delay(500).queue(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("blue").dequeue();
     });
    });

    $('#red').click(function() {
      $(".main").addClass("red").delay(500).queue(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("red").dequeue();
     });
    });

    $('#green').click(function() {
      $(".main").addClass("green").delay(500).queue(function(){
      $(this).removeClass("green").dequeue();
     });
    });

    });
```

My question is how can I go about grouping these click events together so that I'm not repeating the same code block over and over again based on each button's ID?

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20768771/7568271

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register the click event on the common class, then grab the id which is the colour?

```
$(".changer").click(function() {

  let colour = String($(this).attr("id"));

  if (colour) {
       $(".main").addClass(colour).delay(500).queue(function(){
          $(this).removeClass(colour).dequeue();
        });
  }

})
```